# Edit-Merge-Checkin with TFS

Tags: tfs

Does TFS support an Edit/Merge/Checkin model?  It looks like we have to explicitly check out files with the source code explorer to get the readonly bit switched off.  I'm use to files being write enabled, and just having to do a merge before checkin.  Is that model supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  It does.

Right click on the TFS project and select Team Project Settings > Source Control ...  From there you can enable multiple check out.

That said, you still have to use the source control explorer to check out the file; unless you are using Visual Studio to edit it at which point, VS will automatically check out the file.

If you need to use it outside of the source control explorer, you can download the TFS Power tools which adds context menus to the regular file explorer for check in / out / etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, but it is not as confortable as with SVN, you still have to use the source control explorer to check out the file, that will change with [TFS 11 and Local workspaces](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/08/02/version-control-model-enhancements-in-tfs-11.aspx)